# How can I check if an array of strings is empty in MongoDB with java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Imagine I have a DB with documents with the format:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "address": ["adress1","adress2","adress3"]

}
```

Now imagining that can be cases where one id has no addresses

```
{
  "id": "12346",
  "address": [""]

}
```

I have tried, after query the DB and get the document of the id I want, .isEmpty(), but it returns false.

Can this be done using MongoDB?

Comment: Why isn't address an array in your document? it should be `"adress": ["adress1", "adress2", "adress3"]`

Comment: @C.Champagne sorry, it actually is. I corrected it.

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into a list? it is already a list !

Comment: I don't understand. The list isn't empty...

Comment: @D.Lawrence you right I don't need to do that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess I was not clear. I mean in a case where there are no addresses in the key value.

Comment: You'd have to provide a [mcve]. Note that `[""]` means a list with one element, the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to deal with blank addresses (`"address": [""]` is different than  `"address": []` which is different than `"address": null` which is different than not setting the `address` field at all, then you have to query like thisL

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$addFields: {X: {$reduce: {
                input: "$address",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {$sum: [ "$$value", {"$cond":[ {"$ne": ["$$this",""]}, 1, 0]} \
]}
            }}
    }}
,{$match: {"X": {$gt:0} }}
                       ]);
```

We use the `$reduce` function to "walk" the `address` array and check each item to see if it is not a blank string.  If not blank, we increment the `$$value` field which at the end is assigned to new field `X`.  If the array is not present or contains only blank addresses (one or more) then `X` will be zero and we filter those out with the subsequent `$match`.